# Why the Windows Service not call the OnStart method?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I have created a windows service app which has `OnStart` method. The method will read a path from the **app.config** file, create an object, then the service write the object's overridden `ToString()` method to a file with a `StreamWriter`.

This is working when I manually start this service with "**net start**". So the `OnStart` method called, object created and written its `ToString` method to a file.

I set it as an automatic running service, when the Windows starts up.
My problem is, that this `OnStart` method is not called after the service is being started by Windows. So I think when the windows starts running the services at start up, it launches my service just don't calling the `OnStart` method.

Does anybody have the same issue or somebody have a solution for it?

OnStart method:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        filePath = configReader.ReadConfig("FilePath");
        DateEvent dateEvent = new DateEvent(DateTime.Now, TimeLoggerCore.Events.STARTUP.ToString());
        writer.WriteToFile(dateEvent, filePath, true, false);
    }
```

Constructor:

```
public TimeLoggerService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        configReader = new AppConfigReader();
        writer = new CSVWriter();
    }
```

Program.cs:

```
static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new TimeLoggerService()
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
```

Comment: Hard to tell.. no code here..  My onstart code works so we need some example code..  Try a real small service that starts and maybe makes a file in temp.. the code for that would be small

Comment: Added code from the solution.

Comment: Doesnt look like you ever actually run your service. Whats in the program portion

Comment: Where? Because it is a service, it should handle the OnStart event. And as I wrote when I run with "net start" the that method is called. Just when the windows starts up does not.

Comment: in your project should be a program.cs with where the service class is made, and run.. Im wondering if something else is going on.

Comment: Added the program.cs

Comment: Then it suggests something is going wrong. Certainly the onstart should be called.

Comment: Have you looked in the Event Viewer for any exceptions/warnings?

Comment: Yes. But it only says that the service started successfully. Also there was 2 errors but that was because of me.

Answer (score 1):

If the event viewer shows that the service was started successfully, your OnStart has been called and has been returned from. How did you determine that is was not called? I guess by the fact that your file has not been written to. The problem is likely not that your OnStart is not called but that the WriteToFile failed and/or it was written to a different location (e.g. you use a relative path which is different or unavailable during startup). I suggest the following procedure to check this:

- Use System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine to output debug messages in your OnStart
- Download and install/copy the [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) application from Microsoft.
- Configure DebugView to 1) Capture Global Win32, 2) Set a filter on Process Name with your application name and 3) Enable Logging at Boot Time (see the DebugView help).

Experiment a bit with all setting to make sure they work as intended.

Finally, also note this remark in the [OnStart documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart):

> Do not use the constructor to perform processing that should be in OnStart. Use OnStart to handle all initialization of your service. The constructor is called when the application's executable runs, not when the service runs. The executable runs before OnStart. When you continue, for example, the constructor is not called again because the SCM already holds the object in memory. If OnStop releases resources allocated in the constructor rather than in OnStart, the needed resources would not be created again the second time the service is called.

Answer (score 1):

Since your service starts when you attempt to start it from a command-line using `net.exe start [ServiceName]` but fails to start when windows is started, perhaps it is encountering an exception during startup.

One important thing to note when building and working with a custom Windows service is that the Windows Event Log can be very helpful in tracking down problems. When errors occur in a service, it's worthwhile to log that error in the event log.

Another helpful to debug your running service in Visual Studio is to start your service then attach the VS debugger to it.

To get some Windows event log logging into your service, I suggest modifying your service's code to log its startup. Note that what I've posted here is simplified for this forum - I typically put all logging code into a separate class. This way I can use it throughout the life of my service. One important note - be sure to set the `ServiceName` property of your main service class with an appropriate name - this should be done in Visual Studio at design time in the Properties window of the service designer.

```
private EventLog _eventLog;

/*
 * Use the EventId enumeration to store event IDs that will be written with events
 * to the Windows event log.
 */
enum EventId  
{
    ServiceStarting = 10,
    ServiceStartNormal = 100,
    ServiceStartFailure = 999;
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        // remember the event log
        _eventLog = EventLog;

        // log start
        LogMessage(_eventLog, "Service starting", EventLogEntryType.Information, EventId.ServiceStarting);

        filePath = configReader.ReadConfig("FilePath");
        DateEvent dateEvent = new DateEvent(DateTime.Now, TimeLoggerCore.Events.STARTUP.ToString());
        writer.WriteToFile(dateEvent, filePath, true, false);

        LogMessage(_eventLog, "Service started", EventLogEntryType.Information, EventId.ServiceStartNormal);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        LogMessage(_eventLog, e.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error, EventId.ServiceStartFailure);
    }
}

private static void LogMessage(EventLog eventLog, string message, EventLogEntryType entryType, EventId eventId)
{
    /*
     * If the event source we want to log doesn't exist, create it.
     * Note that this take admin privs, and creating the log source should be
     * done during service installation.  This is here as a secondary means
     * to create the log in the event that it doesn't already exist.
     */
    if (!EventLog.SourceExists(eventLog.Source)
    {
        EventLog.CreateEventSource(eventLog.Source, eventLog.Log);
    }
    eventLog.WriteEntry(message, entryType, (int) eventId);
}
```

After adding this code to your service, re-deploy it, restart your system, and then check the event log.  At a minimum you should see a message logged at service start.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my service, and after a lot of digging I found out that the reason why OnStop and OnStart were not called is because of the windows fast startup option.
I put logging in all the functions of the ServiceBase that can be overriden and the one that was called when I shut down my laptop was OnPowerEvent, not OnStop.

[My event log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFwXn.png)

Everything was working as expected when I was restarting windows instead of shutting them down.

Hope that this will help someone.

Answer (score -2):

As you mentioned Windows start up, did you place your executable in the startup folder? If yes, that will not work that way. You need to install the service in the windows service manager. [Microsoft Description for installing services](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-install-and-uninstall-services)

Comment: its said its a windows service.. this is irrelevant

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention, that I installed the service from "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017". And I run this cmd with admin rights. Also I can see the service under the "Services" tab in Management Console.