# The windows service does not do the OnStart function when the PC turns on

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services

I have been programming a windows service that does a SQL Server insert in a database when the PC is turned on and when it is turned off.

When I start the service manually and when I close it manually, it does the Insert, but it's not working when the PC turns on and off. Did I do something wrong?

I code in Visual Studio Code using the Windows Service (.NET) project.

Thanks

I leave part of the code (OnStart, OnShutdown) so you can see what I do:

```
// OnStart
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        InsertaObrir();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("Error Start: " + "\n");
        File.AppendAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.RutaArxiuLog, sb.ToString());
        sb.Clear();
     }
}

// OnShutdown
protected override void OnShutdown()
{
    try
    {
        InsertaSortir();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("Error Sortir: " + "\n");
        File.AppendAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.RutaArxiuLog, sb.ToString());
        sb.Clear();
    }
}

// IntentaObrir 
private void InsertaObrir()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("Inicia: " + DateTime.Now + "\n");
    File.AppendAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.RutaArxiuLog, sb.ToString());
    sb.Clear();

    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.DataSource = Properties.Settings.Default.IP;
    builder.UserID = Properties.Settings.Default.UserID;
    builder.Password = Properties.Settings.Default.Password;
    builder.InitialCatalog = Properties.Settings.Default.BaseDeDades;

    int num = CreateCommand(builder.ConnectionString, true); 
    // This line works so it's not the problem

    sb.Append("Inserta -> " + num + "\n");
    File.AppendAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.RutaArxiuLog, sb.ToString());
    sb.Clear();
}

// IntentaSortir
private void InsertaSortir()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("Apaga: " + DateTime.Now + "\n");
    File.AppendAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.RutaArxiuLog, sb.ToString());
    sb.Clear();

    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.DataSource = Properties.Settings.Default.IP;
    builder.UserID = Properties.Settings.Default.UserID;
    builder.Password = Properties.Settings.Default.Password;
    builder.InitialCatalog = Properties.Settings.Default.BaseDeDades;

    int num = CreateCommand(builder.ConnectionString, false);

    // This line works so it's not the problem
    sb.Append("Inserta -> " + num + "\n");
    File.AppendAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.RutaArxiuLog, sb.ToString());
    sb.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Do you get any exception? Did you declare all required dependicies - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159257/create-dependency-between-windows-services-startup?

Comment: Nope, It doesn't make an error. I've just post the solution. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that Windows 10 has a fast start that makes the OnStart not to trigger (and also the OnShutdown).

I'll leave the post where I found it, and also a website that explains how to disable this function.

Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61307074/16282403

https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10